# send variable back from php to ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Is it possible send back a variable , from a php page, back to the ajax call ?
I mean consider:

```
    ajax.open("POST", "search.php", true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajax.send('username='+"alex");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            var return_data = ajax.responseText;
            document.getElementById("alldrrow").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
```

so far this works fine, but is it possible to send back a special variable from "search.php" back to the ajax call and catch it ?
a variable or anithig, that comes seperate?
so : 
1- send a hole data by echo , from php
2- send a specific string beside that data , simultaneously of course

Comment: Everything you get from `php` file is in `ajax.responseText`

Comment: Yes. echo ur variable and get as responseText

Comment: I know , so how do I send a"Number", or a "STring" , back , and dont let that number or string to show on my page?
I have to work on that string or number with another function

Answer (score 0):

Try to send back a JSON in form of a string and parse it with `JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);`

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP script has to output the value you want back, just use the `echo` function. Then you can access this value into your JS script as the `ajax.responseText`.

The returned value can be JSON formated, or a HTML plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have this in "return_data"?

A better way would be using JSON, you'll find enough tutorials when you google this :)

Comment: It a shame that I can explain correctly :P
I want to sent a specific number , and a hole data(name , ..), but I dont want to show that number in result
did you get ?

Comment: When you use JSON you can send a var that contains the number, and another that contains the result-text to show your user!

Comment: aha :D
OK
that's the one , ok
Im going to read through JASON know :D

Answer (score 0):

if you want ,You can use JSON to return values to your JS script

```
 {
        "result": true,
        "yourVariable": "variableValue"
    }
```

Comment: I know this:(
but I want to send back two data
1- (name , family, ...,a lot data actually)
2- a specific number
but I dont what to show that number of my page
I want to calculate it